# How to have multiple WebSocket streams with PyBit Python library

Tags: python, bybit, python-bybit, pybit

I have multiple bybit accounts and I want to track orders in real time using websockets. This is my python code. It works when there is only one websocket init

```
from bot import ws
import asyncio
import os
from pybit.unified_trading import WebSocket
from time import sleep
import json

ws1 = WebSocket(
    testnet=os.getenv('TESTNET'),
    channel_type="private",
    api_key="XXXXXXX",
    api_secret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
)
ws2 = WebSocket(
    testnet=os.getenv('TESTNET'),
    channel_type="private",
    api_key="YYYYYYY",
    api_secret="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
)

def handle_message(message):
    print(message)

ws1.order_stream(callback=handle_message)
ws2.order_stream(callback=handle_message)
```

but when I run this code it gives me next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Projects\bybot-telegram\main.py", line 31, in <module>
ws1.order_stream(callback=handle_message)
File "C:\Projects\bybot-telegram\venv\Lib\site-packages\pybit\unified_trading.py", line 116, in
order_stream              self.subscribe(topic, callback)
File "C:\Projects\bybot-telegram\venv\Lib\site-packages\pybit\_websocket_stream.py", line 353, in
subscribe               time.sleep(0.1)  
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried using ws_name attribute but then I get new error

```
File "C:\Projects\bybot-telegram\main.py", line 8, in <module>
ws1 = WebSocket(
^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Projects\bybot-telegram\venv\Lib\site-packages\pybit\unified_trading.py", line 69, in
__init__                   super().__init__(WSS_NAME, **kwargs)
TypeError: _V5WebSocketManager.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'ws_name'
```